# Inner join Repeater

Tags: c#, sql

I have got the following tables:

```
# Product
- id
- fk_id
- product_name
- product_text

# Category
- id
- category_name
```

I am using a repeater to output the product_name and product_text, but i wish to output the category_name aswell.

I've tried with a simple inner join, but when doing so, it seems to loop through the category aswell as the products, which it shouldnt.
I only wish to loop through the categories.

I'm sensing that i should another loop than repeater to execute this properly.

Edit:

```
SELECT product.product_name, product_text, category.category_name
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category ON product.fk_id = category.id
```

I just wanna know if i can loop through the product table in a repeater, without it looping the category table aswell.

Comment: What does your SQL inner join statement look like?

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want your output to look?

Comment: I'm guessing each product is in multiple categories and that's causing multiple rows per product - how do you want the categories displayed? All of them comma-separated? Just the first one?